# How do you get the settings.py file of a django project to read from .env?

Tags: django-email

I am trying to configure email environment settings in my django project. I am using django-environ package. I have pasted this code:

```
EMAIL_CONFIG = env.email_url('EMAIL_URL',default='smtp://user@:password@localhost:25')
vars().update(EMAIL_CONFIG)
```

in my .env file. But when i run the server am getting an error saying:

```
"django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Set the EMAIL_CONFIG environment variable"
```

what am getting wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this settings should part of your `.env`. This file should look like this

```
DEBUG=on
SECRET_KEY=your-secret-key
DATABASE_URL=psql://user:un-githubbedpassword@127.0.0.1:8458/database
SQLITE_URL=sqlite:///my-local-sqlite.db
CACHE_URL=memcache://127.0.0.1:11211,127.0.0.1:11212,127.0.0.1:11213
REDIS_URL=rediscache://127.0.0.1:6379/1?client_class=django_redis.client.DefaultClient&password=ungithubbed-secret
```

I guess your settings (taken from the docs) should be used inside `settings.py` or in a custom `email_config`

```
EMAIL_CONFIG = env.email_url('EMAIL_URL',default='smtp://user@:password@localhost:25')
vars().update(EMAIL_CONFIG)
```

Check the installation and usage docs from [django-environ](https://django-environ.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#installation).

Comment: Alright thanks.. I ended up putting the Email settings in my .bashrc file.  I am using linux. And the .env file holds only the SECRET_KEY. Everything is working now.

Comment: Great to hear that. As a new so contributor you may interested in reading [why vote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) and [some-answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Okay will take a look.